# Alamofire error is always nil, while request fails

Tags: swift, alamofire

In case of 400(bad request) or 403(unauthorized) I can grab info about fail only from response, while error,passed in param is always nil - do it needs any extra setup?

```
 Alamofire.request(Router.SignIn(emailField.text, passwordField.text)).response { (request, response, data, error)  in

        println(error)
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
```

UPD: as mattt advised added valide like this:

```
        Alamofire.request(UdacityRouter.SignIn(emailField.text, passwordField.text)).validate().response
       in

        println(error)
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
```

As result I received `"Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.alamofire.error error -1.)")"` What is far away from meaningfull explanation of failure.. I wonder why I can't simply get error with a simple failure explanation as AFNetworking does..

Comment: You need to add .validate() if you want HTTP status codes to produce errors.

Comment: thanks, i'l try it! but won't it be more usefull to add this behaviour by default?

Comment: No. Content-Type and Status Code validation are purposefully opt-in with Alamofire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to add .validate() because of by default, Alamofire treats any completed request to be successful, regardless of the content of the response.

From Alamofire documentation:

> **Validation**
>
> By default, Alamofire treats any completed request to be successful,
>   regardless of the content of the response. Calling validate before a
>   response handler causes an error to be generated if the response had
>   an unacceptable status code or MIME type.
>
> *Manual Validation*
>
> ```
> Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
>          .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
>          .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
>          .response { _, _, _, error in
>              println(error)
>          }
> ```
>
> *Automatic Validation*
>
> Automatically validates status code within 200...299 range, and that
>   the Content-Type header of the response matches the Accept header of
>   the request, if one is provided.
>
> ```
> Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
>          .validate()
>          .response { _, _, _, error in
>              println(error)
>          }
> ```